# Disconnecting an Oracle Session from a Logon Trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I'm trying to construct an Oracle 11g logon trigger that restricts access for a specific user to a known list of applications. For example, user `SCOTT` can only connect with `MYAPP.EXE`.

I believe I have the correct trigger and logic, but the problem I'm having is that the `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR();` doesn't kill the session.
The trigger is enabled, and I've tried granting the `ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER` privilege, but I'm still missing something.

Based on the [this example](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Disconnecting-session-from-an-on-logon-trigger,10), here's the trigger I have so far (owned by the same user):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER global_logon_trg AFTER logon ON DATABASE
DECLARE
   p_session_user  varchar2(64);
   p_module        varchar2(64);
BEGIN
   SELECT UPPER(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')) INTO p_session_user FROM DUAL;
   SELECT UPPER(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'MODULE')) INTO p_module FROM DUAL;

   DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER(p_session_user || '-' || p_module);

   IF ((p_session_user = 'SCOTT') AND (p_module IN ('MYAPP.EXE'))) THEN
      DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('about to raise app_error..');
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,'You are not allowed to connect to the database');
   END IF;

END;
/
```

But logging in as `SCOTT` with SQL*Plus still works. And if I then query `v$session`, with the following query:

```
select username, client_identifier
from v$session
where username not in ('SYSMAN', 'DBSNMP');
```

I get the following result..

```
USERNAME           CLIENT_IDENTIFIER
------------------ -----------------------------------
SCOTT              about to raise app_error..
```

**What am I missing?**  Is this a privileges thing, a trigger code thing, or an [Oracle bug](http://www.red-database-security.com/advisory/bypass_oracle_logon_trigger.html) thing?  Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?! (I have full control over the Database and the Server it sits on, if that makes it any easier!)

I'm using `Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production`

Many thanks for your help, and suggestions

Andrew  :o)

Comment: Some great answers from @Vincent and @Guy, and after reading through the links they've provided, I don't think I'll be implementing this logon disconnect trigger, even though I've now got it working!  :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out TOM KYTE's blog / Q&A site [asktom](http://asktom.oracle.com).  There may be a subtle reason why this is not working as you would expect.

Your problem discussed [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:561622956788)  and [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3236035522926) for two examples.

An alternative is to use APPLICATION ROLES that are only enabled by the application and a password configured in the application.

As a DBA I would not like to restrict access to the database via SQLPLUS under any circumstances as this is often your best route to gain access to a sickly database.  And to have it in a global trigger.  No way matey!

Comment: The second of your example links fixed the issue - in trying to get it to work I had granted 'Administer Database Trigger' - revoking this privilege prevents the user from logging in as desired  :o)

Answer (score 1):

Has the Scott schema been granted the DBA role? From [this discussion on Asktom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:561622956788#26189316939834), it seems a member of the DBA group can't be disconnected with an ON LOGON trigger.

By the way you will also see in that thread why your solution is not bullet-proof (eg: `copy sqlplus.exe foo.exe`)

**Update:** additionaly this trigger won't work in the following cases:

- the owner of the trigger is SCOTT (i-e: he won't be disconnected if he actually owns the trigger, this must be to prevent accidental self-locking),
- the user has the privilege *Administer Database Trigger*

Could you please check if the trigger is owned by SCOTT ?

Comment: Thanks. SCOTT isn't a DBA, and I tried TOAD instead of SQL*Plus - in case the latter is a special case - and the login is still allowed. Thanks for the xcopy workaround - I had thought of that, though I'd still like to get it working so as to understand why the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @Andrew: I updated my answer: apparently the trigger won't disconnect the OWNER of the trigger.

Comment: Thanks again - I didn't know the OWNER made a difference as well - in my case the Trigger was owned by a different DBA user :o)